# Objective-C  reference to a pointer declaration getting error

Tags: objective-c

I had this declaration.

```
- (BOOL)getNHPData:(REMOTE_MESS_ID)msgId withEvent:(RSEvent*&)pEvent;
```

I tried with `RSEvent**` also but i'm getting this error for 2 times

```
Expected ')' before RSEvent
```

Why is it so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally have never had much success in c++ or obj-c with pointer references, if I need that kind of functionality, I usually just use a pointer pointer like this:

```
some function()
{
    RSEvent *pEvent = new RSEvent();
    [self getNHPData:DEFAULT_MSG_ID withEbvent:&pEvent];
}

- (BOOL)getNHPData:(REMOTE_MESS_ID)msgId withEvent:(RSEvent**)pEvent
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Objective-C is a superset of the C language and does not have references. If you want to use C++-style references in Objective-C, you must compile as Objective-C++ (as you might expect, Objective-C++ is a superset of C++). Use the `.mm` extension to automatically use the Objective-C++ in Xcode.

If the method in question is a public API that will be consumed from Objective-C, I would highly recommend using a pointer-to-pointer (`RSEvent**`) instead of a pointer reference. Using Objective-C++ in a header "infects" clients with Objective-C++ (unless you're very careful). Objective-C++ takes *much* longer to compile that Objective-C and you will eventually run into the inevitable C vs. C++ incompatibilities. Standard practice is to hide Objective-C++ from public APIs whenever possible.